# Proof that 2 phase locking produces order preserving Conflict serializable schedules

Tags: correctness-proof, database-theory, database-concurrency, transactions

In the book **Transactional information systems: theory, algorithms, and the practice of concurrency control and recovery** there is a theorem stating that Gen(2PL) ⊂ OCSR. Can some one help to guide on how to prove this

i.e; Prove that the histories produced by the basic two-phase locking protocol are Order Perserving Conflict Serializable (OPCSR), that is the order of non-interleaved transactions is preserved in the equivalent serial order of transactions.